# Parameter passing to stored procedures in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

I have a SQL procedure that I'm calling from my c# code.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertData", con, transaction);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@IP_No", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
cmd.Parameters["@IP_No"].Value = data.IP_No;

result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
```

This is my procedure:

```
(
@IP_No varchar(15),       
@Indent_No varchar(20)
)
AS
BEGIN
set @Indent_No = (SELECT IndentId from IdTable)

INSERT INTO InsertData(IP_No,Indent_No)
VALUES(@IP_No,@Indent_No)

Update IdTable set IndentId=IndentId+1;

END
```

Basically, I want my ID to be pulled from a database where I keep incrementing it.
It throws this error:

> Procedure or function  expects parameter @Indent_No which was not
>   supplied.

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

As you use `@Indent_No` only internally within the stored procedure, you don't need to declare it as an input parameter. You need to declare it within the body of your stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertData
(
@IP_No varchar(15)
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Indent_No varchar(20)

set @Indent_No = (SELECT IndentId from IdTable)

INSERT INTO InsertData(IP_No,Indent_No)
VALUES(@IP_No,@Indent_No)

Update IdTable set IndentId=IndentId+1;

END
```